# Как осуществить jmp на нужный мне адрес. Потом перевести в байткод

Tags: ассемблер, адрес, машинный-код

Интересует такой вопрос. Мне нужно совершить `jmp` из адреса `FFFFC20AD0F8FFA0` в `FFFFF80121214CE0`. Как я понимаю надо рассчитать смещение и использовать `jmp far`, но информации об том как это сделать я не нашел. Хотелось бы узнать именно порядок действий `jmp` в нужный адрес -> машинный код.

Comment: Если Вы знаете адрес назначения, то почему не просто не прыгнуть прямо на этот адрес? `JMP FAR ptr`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для адресов с такой большой разницей (0x35f650284d40, больше двойного слова) сделать относительный прыжок не получится:
[image]

Но можно сделать переход по абсолютному адресу в регистре:

```
use64
; org 0xFFFFC20AD0F8FFA0 ; Т.к. прыжок по абсолютному адресу, начальный адрес указывать не обязательно
mov rax, 0xFFFFF80121214CE0
jmp rax
```

fasm компилирует в такой набор байт (в шестнадцатеричном виде):

```
48 B8 E0 4C 21 21 01 F8 FF FF FF E0
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! Вы не подскажите, где можно более подробно изучить связь ассемблера и машинного кода? (может существует книга или еще что-нибудь)

Comment: Есть [мануалы intel по системе команд x86](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html). Для ознакомления можно почитать статью Криса Касперски "Тонкости дизассемблирования (дизассемблирование в уме)". Плюс на Хабре были какие-то статьи по этой теме.